# Spring Data Mongodb: json string to BasicDBObject

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've created this custom converter:

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
public class MetadataWriterConverter implements Converter<Metadata, DBObject> {
    @Override
    public DBObject convert(Metadata metadata) {
        DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
        dbObject.put("name", metadata.getName());
        dbObject.put("metadata", (BasicDBObject) BasicDBObject.parse(reference.getMetadata())); 
        dbObject.removeField("_class");
        return dbObject;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this exception:

> Caused by: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.

The problem is on:

```
(BasicDBObject) BasicDBObject.parse(metadata.getMetadata())
```

the content of `metadata.getMetadata` is: `"[{'departament': 'JUST'}]"`.

`Metadata` class is:

```
public class Metadata {
    private String id;
    private String user;
    private String metadata;
}
```

The content of `metadata` field is a json string, I'm trying to convert to `BasicDbObject`, but the problem appears when this string is an json array: `[{},{}]`.

Guess:

```
Metadata met = new Metadata();
met.setId("Mdt1");
met.setUser("user");
met.setMetadata("[{'departament': 'JUST'}]");
```

What I want to get is:

```
{
  "id": Mdt1,
  "user": "user",
  "metadata": [{"departament": "JUST"}]
}
```

Any ideas about how to refactor my converter?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `BasicDBObject.parse()` expects a `JSONObject` instead of a `JSONArray` that you are passing in your example. Check the docs here - http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#parse-java.lang.String-

Instead, you can try converting your `reference.getMetadata()` into a `valid JSON String` and then using `BasicDBList` for your `JSONArray`. Something like below:

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
public class MetadataWriterConverter implements Converter<Metadata, DBObject> 
{
    @Override
    public DBObject convert(Metadata metadata) {
        DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
        dbObject.put("name", metadata.getName());
        String jsonString = String.format("{\"data\": " + reference.getMetadata() + "}");
        BasicDBObject basicDBObject = (BasicDBObject) BasicDBObject.parse(jsonString);
        BasicDBList parsedList = (BasicDBList) basicDBObject.get("data");
        dbObject.put("metadata", parsedList); 
        dbObject.removeField("_class");
        return dbObject;
    }
}
```